# Equivalent of Firefox's "error console" in other browsers

Tags: javascript, browser

Is there an equivalent to Firefox's "Error console" in other browsers? I find the error console handy for finding JavaScript errors, but there doesn't seem to be an equivalent simple way to see error messages on other browsers. I'm interested in Internet Explorer, Opera and Google Chrome.

**Post script:** I'm not looking for an alternative to Firefox's error console, it is fine for me. I don't need FireBug. Also I am aware of the Developer Tools in Google Chrome, but I can't make sense of it. I just want to get the error messages. Is there some way to get sane error messages out of it? I haven't been able to. My default browser is Chrome on Windows and Linux, but if I do something in JavaScript, I end up having to switch to Firefox to get the error messages from the error console.

Comment: ★ This question was entered entirely via a Nintendo Wii. ★

Comment: This comment was entered entirely on a desktop computer (running Opera, as it were).

Comment: I got some surprised remarks on meta.stackoverflow.com when I said that parts of the site didn't work on the Wii browser, so I just wanted to point that out.

Comment: See also [How to open the JavaScript console in different browsers?](http://webmasters.stackexchange.com/q/8525) at [webmasters.SE]

Answer (score 34, accepted):

You have following options

- **Chrome**: Press <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Shift</kbd>+<kbd>J</kbd> (<kbd>Cmd</kbd>+<kbd>Option</kbd>+<kbd>J</kbd> on Mac) and it will give similar functionality. Also consider checking out [JavaScript debugger](http://www.pascarello.com/lessons/browsers/ChromeDebugHelp.html) in Chrome
- **IE7**: Nothing built in. But have a look at [IE Developer Toolbar](http://www.microsoft.com/downloads/details.aspx?familyid=e59c3964-672d-4511-bb3e-2d5e1db91038&displaylang=en)
- **IE8**: Just hit <kbd>F12</kbd> and you will get access to some very capable built-in tools. Error console is on `Script` tab
- **Firefox**: <strike>Just use [FireBug](http://getfirebug.com/)</strike> Press <kbd>F12</kbd>.  The built-in tools are now quiet good.
- **Opera**: Press <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Shift</kbd>+<kbd>I</kbd> (<kbd>Cmd</kbd>+<kbd>Option</kbd>+<kbd>I</kbd> on Mac) to launch [Opera Drangonfly](http://www.opera.com/dragonfly/documentation/) which is a fully featured development and debugging tool integrated into the Opera browser
- **Safari**: Enable the Developer Menu from Safari's preferences. It will give access the various tools (Error Console, Web Inspector, JavaScript Profiler, etc). Of course there are also shortcuts, like <kbd>Cmd</kbd> + <kbd>Alt</kbd> + <kbd>C</kbd> for the console

Comment: IE8 has some very capable built-in tools. Just hit F12.

Comment: IE developer toolbar for IE7 does not provide JS error output.  It only allows you to access the HTML/CSS of a page.

Answer (score 3):

I use Ctrl+Shift+J in Chrome, and it's got something close in there.  IE -- there's the [IE Developer Toolbar](http://www.microsoft.com/downloads/details.aspx?familyid=e59c3964-672d-4511-bb3e-2d5e1db91038&displaylang=en), and I think IE8 has something like that, but let's face it, if you're using IE for Javascript debugging, you basically hate yourself and have more serious personal issues regarding your self-esteem to deal with.

Comment: Then again, you might have to debug JavaScript in IE because it doesn't work there but works elsewhere.

Comment: Very true.  But where I work, there's an inexplicable desire to use IE for development.

Comment: Jquery works flawlessly in firefox,chrome,safari,my shoe,a bucket.  Fails miserably in i.e.,  trying to get IE to tell me why === nightmare.

Comment: From IE10, the developer tools in IE is actually quite useful.

Comment: UNTIL you try to inspect an element that was dynamically created.  Not even IE 11 can do that.  Chrome can.  Debugging thorough IE is significantly better than 5 years ago when I wrote this, but it's still not competitive.

Answer (score 1):

Any of [*these*](http://www.delightbite.com):

> ```
> Hit F12 or Ctrl+Shift+I
> right-click on any element on the page, and "Inspect Element"
> Wrench button -> Tools -> Developer Tools
> ```

Then go to Console tab

Answer (score 0):

If you use Firefox's error-console you should consider the [Firebug](http://getfirebug.com) plugin.

There is also Firebug Lite -- a bookmarklet that brings a scaled-down version of Firebug to other browsers.

Comment: Thanks for the tip, but I am looking for an equivalent for the error console in other browsers.

Answer (score 0):

In Opera it's under `Tools->Advanced->Error Console`. I find it very handy.

Answer (score 0):

- **Safari:** Enable the Developer Menu from Safari's preferences, then use that menu to access the various tools (Error Console, Web Inspector, JavaScript Profiler, ...). Of course there are also shortcuts, like CMD + ALT + C for the console. :)

Answer (score 0):

I have taken to the practice of the following before DOM load:

```
(function(window, undefined){
  var debug_print = (location.search.indexOf('debug') != -1);
  if(window['console'] == undefined){
    var _logs = [];
    var _console = {
      log : function(){
        _logs.push({'msg':Array.prototype.slice.call(arguments, 0), 'type':null});
        this._out();
      },
      warn : function(){
        _logs.push({'msg':Array.prototype.slice.call(arguments, 0), 'type':'warn'});
        this._out();
      },
      error : function(){
        _logs.push({'msg':Array.prototype.slice.call(arguments, 0), 'type':'error'});
        this._out();
      },
      _out : function(){
        if(debug_print && typeof this['write'] == 'function'){
          this.write(_logs.pop());
        }
      },
      _print : function(){return debug_print;},
      _q : function(){return _logs.length;},
      _flush : function(){
        if(typeof this['write'] == 'function'){
          _logs.reverse();
          for(var entry; entry = _logs.pop();){
            this.write(entry);
          }
        }
      }
    }
    window['console'] = _console;
  }
})(window)
```

and this after domload (place it at the end of the body tag):

```
(function(window, undefined){
  if(window['console']){
    if(console['_print']){
      var console_pane = document.createElement('div');
      console_pane.id = '_debug_console';
      document.body.appendChild(console_pane);
      console.write = function(log){
        var msg = [new Date(), log.msg].join("$/> ");
        var entry_pane = document.createElement('div');
        if(log.type !== undefined){
          entry_pane.className = log.type;
        };
        console_pane.appendChild(entry_pane);
        entry_pane.innerHTML = msg;
      };
      console._flush();
    };
  }
})(window)
```

This allows you to do all the basics and turn the actual console display mechanism off and on with the `?debug` querystring (it can be placed anywhere in the querystring). To make it look less atrocious you might also want to bundle in the following css:

```
#_debug_console{
  background : #ffffff;
  margin: 0px;
  position: fixed;
  bottom: 0;
  width: 100%;
  height: 20%;
  font-family: Arial;
  font-size: 10px;
  border-top: solid 5px #ddd;
}
#_debug_console .error{
  color: #FF0000;
}
#_debug_console .warn{
  color: #DDDD00;
}
```

Comment: I would look into Blackbird for JS.  Seems liek a much simpler approach to your goals.

Comment: yeah, I actually don't do this anymore. For the most part I just buffer the logs through a proxy method and store them in an array for later retrieval. The UI is less fun but the access is the same.