# Javascript check for spaces

Tags: javascript, spaces

I have this function but I want to check for spaces only in the front and back, not in the middle before i sent back what can i do with it...

```
function validateNumeric() {
  var val = document.getElementById("tbNumber").value;
  var validChars = '0123456789.'; 

  for(var i = 0; i < val.length; i++){ 
    if(validChars.indexOf(val.charAt(i)) == -1){
    alert('Please enter valid number');
    return false; 
    } 
  }
  return true; 
  }
```

Comment: What does checking for leading/trailing spaces have to do with checking to see if the input is a valid number?

Answer (score 12):

Time for [regular expressions](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/JavaScript/Guide/Regular_Expressions).

```
function startsOrEndsWithWhitespace(str)
{
    return /^\s|\s$/.test(str);
}
```

Tests:

```
> /^\s|\s$/.test('123454')
  false
> /^\s|\s$/.test('123 454')
  false
> /^\s|\s$/.test(' 123454')
  true
> /^\s|\s$/.test(' 123454 ')
  true
> /^\s|\s$/.test('123454 ')
  true
```

---

> if i dont wanna accept 1 1 what do i have to change

```
function containsWhitespace(str)
{
    return /\s/.test(str);
}
```

Tests:

```
> /\s/.test('123454')
  false
> /\s/.test('123 454')
  true
> /\s/.test(' 123454')
  true
> /\s/.test('123454 ')
  true
> /\s/.test(' 123454 ')
  true
> /\s/.test(' 123 454 ')
  true
```

Comment: ... or `return /^\s|\s$/.test(str);` - à chacun son goût

Comment: @jack Start at http://regexlib.com/DisplayPatterns.aspx?cattabindex=2&categoryId=3 for ideas :)

Comment: @Pointy already decided I prefer `re.test(string)` before I saw your comment `:)`

Comment: This actually answers the badly formulated question. :J

Comment: is it going to accept 1.1 coz i need to say ok to number with decimal

Comment: @jack just how hard would it be to test that yourself? Allow me to introduce you to your browser's console: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1648582/equivalent-of-firefoxs-error-console-in-other-browsers

Comment: @jack I've create a [jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/qDPeW/) for you to *try and edit* until you've solve the issue :-)

Answer (score 1):

For a really simple solution, if you can use jQuery, use jQuery.trim() and compare the trimmed string with the original. If not equal, then there were spaces so the number is invalid.

Answer (score 0):

```
function validateNumeric() {
  var val = document.getElementById("tbNumber").value;
  if (!/^\s*(?:\d+(?:\.\d*)?|\.\d+)\s*$/.test(val)) {
    alert('Please enter a valid number');
    return false; 
  }
  return true;
}
```

`(?:\d+(?:\.\d*)|\.\d+)` breaks down as follows:

1. `\d+` is any number of digits, e.g. 123
2. `(\.\d*)?` optionally matches a fraction, e.g. .25 and . or blank but not .1.2
3. `\.\d+` matches a fraction without an integer part as in .5 but not 1.5.
4. `(?:abc|def)` groups things together and matches either `abc` or `def`

`/^\s*(?:\d+(?:\.\d*)|\.\d+)\s*$/` means any number of spaces followed by one or more decimal digits followed by any number of spaces.  So it does what your `validChars` loop did plus allows spaces at the start and end.

Answer (score 0):

```
function trim (myString)
{
return myString.replace(/^\s+/g,'').replace(/\s+$/g,'')
}
```

[source](http://www.commentcamarche.net/forum/affich-796470-javascript-trim-sur-une-chaine-possible)

Comment: "check for spaces" != "remove spaces"

Answer (score 0):

To trim your string you can write something like this, as it's been said before:

```
function trim(str){
    return str.replace(/^\s+|\s+$/g), '');
}
```

But why bother?
Want you really want is:

```
function validateNumeric(str) {
    return !isNaN(parseFloat(str));
}
```

Note your original code accepts something like "..." or "7.8..9" as being numeric, which is wrong.

**Update**: kennebec has called my attention to the fact that `parseFloat()` will ignore trailing garbage at the end of string. So I call your attention to this alternative given in an answer to question ["Validate numbers in JavaScript - IsNumeric()"](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18082/validate-numbers-in-javascript-isnumeric/1830844#1830844):

```
function isNumber(n) {
    return !isNaN(parseFloat(n)) && isFinite(n);
}
```

(Original credit goes to [CMS](https://stackoverflow.com/users/5445/cms)).

Comment: This will accept input that starts with a number but can include anything after that. if(parseFloat(str)+''===str) would do.