# javascript validation for numbers

Tags: javascript, validation

can someone tell me what i am doing wrong here.. i am not getting invalid number alert when i enter 1 1 0r a

```
function validateNumeric() {
  var old_val = document.getElementById("tbNumber").value;
  var new_val = old_val.replace(/^\s+|\s+$/g,"");
  var validChars = '0123456789.'; 

  for(var i = 0; i < val.length; i++){ 
    if(validChars.indexOf(new_val.charAt(i)) == -1){
      alert('Please enter valid number');
      return false; 
    } else {
        document.getElementById("tbNumber").value = new_val;
      }
  }
  return true; 
}
```

Comment: Duplicate http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6228041/javascript-check-for-spaces ?

Comment: what was wrong with the top answer when you asked this before?

Comment: i don't think it is a duplicate - see my answer.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In your `for` loop test, you're referencing a variable `val`, which probably comes back as having a length of `0`, so your loop will never do anything and the function will simply return true. I'm guessing your `for` loop should actually look like:

```
for(var i = 0; i < new_val.length; i++){
    ...
}
```

Answer (score 0):

There is a much simpler solution: use a [regular expression](http://www.regular-expressions.info/reference.html).

Your valid characters are the **digits** 0 -9, including a decimal point, correct? Well, the RegEx for that is **\d**. Therefore, this would check if the value entered is numeric:

```
(/\d/).test( myValue );
```

Therefore, your code just needs to use the RegEx instead of an expensive loop.

```
function validateNumeric(){
    var x = document.getElementById('foo');
    var y = x.value.replace(/^\s+|\s+$/g,'');
    var DIGITS = (/\d/); // Uppercase because this is a constant value

    if (!DIGITS.test( y )){
        alert('Please enter a valid number.');
        return false;
    } else {
        x.value = y;
        return true;
    }
}
```

Comment: thanx for the help but if someone enter 2..2 than how can i test that